# Could we bend electric field in the air?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I have been thinking, if magnetic field can bend currents, can they bend electric field as well? If they can't, then what would be a possible way? (the field is in the air, the anode and cathode are also exposed to the air) And by bend I mean this: [image]

Comment: What do you mean by _bend_?

Comment: How do you think the field lines will be without the magnetic field?

Comment: Sorry, that diagram is just for showing, what I mean is that you could twist and turn the field like a prezel between the two electrod no matter what the electrod look like?